# Best way to include style files

Tags: php, include, head

What's the better way to include style files, js scripts, script code block for separate pages?

For example I have 3 pages, index.php, about.php, contact.php and general header for them.
And for index.php i need only css style file, so it's not logical to include all other files like jquery, fancybox, somepopup.js and other, but for about.php i needed to include jquery and fancybox, and for contact.php I don't need fancybox, but need jquery and some, my block code like,

```
<style>
  $('.lalala').bind('click', function() {
    //some code lalala
  });
</style>
```

And what is the best, and the fastest way (for compiler) to do it ?
I used something like this
`($_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] == '/index.php' || $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] == '/banana.php')? '<script src="js/ckeditor/my_conf.js"></script>' :''`

But when I have more than 5 files, and some block code which I need to pass in header depending on the page, its look really bad. So maybe there is better way to do it ?

Answer (score 0):

The best solution will be merging all the files into one. For instance, you can create `application.js` and `application.css`. You can do it manually or dynamically in PHP.

```
$css = scandir('./css/');
$apllicationCSS = array();

foreach($css as $file)
{
    if($file !== '.' and $file !== '..')
    {
        $apllicationCSS[] = file_get_contents('./css/' .  $file);
    }
} 

file_put_contents('application.css', implode("\n", $applicationCSS));
```

I didn't test it, but you should get overall idea. The code need to be improved. You can make subdirectories working recursivly or remove blank spaces to minimalize weight of the file.